# UIBarButton item

Tags: iphone

I want to add custom button in the navigation bar..
can any one suggest how to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a simple uibutton on view. set the properties you required and drag it on to navigation bar.

or you can try this

```
UIButton *btnPrev =[[UIButton alloc] init];
[btnPrev setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnPrevious.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnPrev.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 30);
[btnPrev addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *btnBack =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnPrev];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnBack;
```

Thanks